# Rewrite $y$ = $ax^2$ $exp \left(-\frac bx \right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to rewrite the following equation so that $x$ is a function of $y$ ?

$y$ = $ax^2$ $exp \left(-\frac bx \right)$

Where $a$ and $b$ are constants and $ x > 0 $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ x = \dfrac{b}{2 W\left( \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{a b^2/y}\right)}$$
where $W$ is the Lambert W function.  Assuming $ab^2 > 0$, you want to use the
principal branch of $W$.

Comment: $ab^2 > 0$. Would you know a good internet link about the Lambert W function and the principal branch?

Comment: W function is a tricksy thing, could have sworn I tried to use it here and had no luck. But the algebra checks out, good work.

Comment: $W_{0}(x)=\sum _{{n=1}}^{\infty }{\frac {(-n)^{{n-1}}}{n!}}\ x^{n}=x-x^{2}+{\frac {3}{2}}x^{3}-{\frac {8}{3}}x^{4}+{\frac {125}{24}}x^{5}-\cdots$                         Would this be a correct Taylor series expansion of the principal branch of the Lambert W function?

Comment: Or would it be better to use:
$W_{{0}}(x)=L_{1}-L_{2}+{\frac {L_{2}}{L_{1}}}+{\frac {L_{2}(-2+L_{2})}{2L_{1}^{2}}}+{\frac {L_{2}(6-9L_{2}+2L_{2}^{2})}{6L_{1}^{3}}}+{\frac {L_{2}(-12+36L_{2}-22L_{2}^{2}+3L_{2}^{3})}{12L_{1}^{4}}}+\cdots$

Comment: $W_{{0}}(x)=L_{1}-L_{2}+\sum _{{\ell =0}}^{{\infty }}\sum _{{m=1}}^{{\infty }}{\frac {(-1)^{{\ell }}\left[{\begin{matrix}\ell +m\\\ell +1\end{matrix}}\right]}{m!}}L_{1}^{{-\ell -m}}L_{2}^{{m}}$
where $L_{1}=\ln x, L_{2}=\ln \ln x$ and $\left[{\begin{matrix}\ell +m\\\ell +1\end{matrix}}\right]$ is a non-negative Stirling number of the first kind.

Comment: A standard reference: Corless, Gonnet, Hare, Jeffrey and Knuth "On the Lambert W function" https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Try plotting an example of it, e.g. with $a = b = 1$. There are values of $y$ which correspond to more than one different $x$ value, so there cannot be an inverse function.

Comment: Assume the function is defined only for the positive x axis. Can there be a function, or it is still impossible?

Comment: In that case $y$ is strictly increasing, so there is a function, but it might not be expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Is there a possible series representation of the inverse? Would you know how to find one?

Comment: @Heisenberg I played around with the derivative of the inverse formula, but it didn't get very far. There probably is a good technique, but I'm not aware of it.